# Move sub-site into sub-heading in navigation?

Tags: navigation, site

I've just created some sub-sites that I'd like to be grouped on the left navigation - I've adding in the headings which appear as folders, but I can't seem to find a way to move sites from the base level navigation into these newly created folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions below:

[image]

[image]

And the change should reflect in Left Navigation immediately after your click OK.

Comment: You're a star, thank you! I tried this last night on Safari and it seemed to be shunting it above the navigation, but it's working perfectly now in IE8, thanks :)